# How to enable Twig syntax for HTML/PHP files in PhpStorm?

Tags: twig, syntax-highlighting, phpstorm, syntax-checking

I'm having trouble getting Twig syntax checking and highlighting for `*.php` and `*.tpl*` files in PhpStorm? It throws a lot of syntax errors. The *HTML* and *PHP* syntax is already getting picked up.

In *Settings* | *File Types* | *Twig*, I can't add filetype `*.php` because it's already in use and it asks me to replace it.

Comment: There is no other way -- only by associating file extensions in `Settings | File Types | Twig` (yep -- pattern can only be associated with one file type at a time) . BTW -- why do you use twig in PHP files?

Comment: I use Twig in files with a PHP extension for some frameworks that load their HTML templates that way.

Comment: But why not renaming them with the *.html.twig extension ?

Comment: That's outside the scope of the question. They're not my files and it's possible to render correct highlighting on mixed HTML, PHP and JavaScript for example.

Comment: Are you using Symfony2? In this case, you could use the Symfony plugin